# Windows SBS 2008 Upgrade

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, backup

When we started our company we have implemented Small Business Server 2008 but now we are growing so fast so we need to upgrade. Can anyone suggest me which server is more efficient to get. limit of users is actual about to finish.

Answer (score 2):

Just upgrade the server from Small Business server to Windows 2008 Standard edition.  However if you are using Exchange or SQL Server you'll need to purchase those licenses and the needed CALs.